Jupiter / SOLANA How to swap 2 times in 1 with /swap-instructions
Hello everybody i need your help please
I'm trying to swap 2 time in 1 with Jupiter Dex
So what i do ?
I build a code for Solana swap on jupiter that fetch quote when calling 2 differents swap-instructions
https://quote-api.jup.ag/v6/quote?

So i receive 2 quotes after i call swap-instructions from this 2 both quotes
After i received 2 swap-instructions
When trying to send these both 2 swap-instruction i do :
        const { swapTransaction } = await getSwapTransaction(
      [quote0,quote1] // HERE THE PROBLEM
      wallet.publicKey.toString()
    );

    // 3. Deserialize transaction
    const transaction = VersionedTransaction.deserialize(
      Buffer.from(swapTransaction, 'base64')
    );

    // 4. Execute and confirm transaction
    const { txid, confirmation } = await executeTransaction(
      connections.primary,
      transaction,
      wallet
    );

    console.log(`Transaction successful: https://solscan.io/tx/${txid}`);

async function getSwapTransaction(quoteResponse, userPublicKey) {
  const response = await fetch(`${QUOTE_API}/swap`, {
    method: 'POST',
    headers: { 'Content-Type': 'application/json' },
    body: JSON.stringify({
      quoteResponse,
      userPublicKey,
      wrapAndUnwrapSol: true,
      priorityLevelWithMaxLamports: {
        priorityLevel: "veryHigh",
        maxLamports: PRIORITY_FEE_LIMIT
      }
    })
  });

  if (!response.ok) {
    throw new Error(`Swap transaction failed: ${response.statusText}`);
  }
  return response.json();
}

But the problem return at getSwapTransaction : Unprocessable Entity
I'm loss because it work with 1 swap

Jupiter don't allow circular trade with public RPC

I guess you need to fetch each swap instruction separately. At least, it is stated in the docs of Jupiter. Then you can try to combine them into one transaction (VersionedTransaction).

Yes they help me to solve my issue but do you know how to do a VersionedTransaction ? with 2 swap-instructions ?

You can check the Solana docs or examples in the Chainstack tutorial on Raydium:
https://github.com/chainstacklabs/raydium-sdk-swap-example-typescript/blob/94668aca0ebc0b2a245e83c765f7e98b7ce37048/src/RaydiumSwap.ts#L138
P.S. I'm a Developer Advocate at Chainstack.

i ask to jupiter dicord ty
